# Maximize redo rate on replica side of an Availability Group

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

My SQL Server databases are hosted on a highly spec'd converged platform with All Flash Storage Arrays, 40G network etc.

However, we're still unable to get more than 50MB/s Redo Rate - I need this to be in the GB/sec range.

The supporting platform can handle this - what is the bottleneck within SQL Server 2012 that stops it from maximizing the potential throughput and how can I overcome it? Even with a single-threaded process 50MB/s is poor - and totally useless given the amount of data we process.

Updates:
When I'm on the server I can copy files between drives and get speeds > 1000MB/s.
After reboots I see Redo Rates spike as high as 300MB/s, so I know its possible in my environment, however it quickly reduces to its norm of 50MB/s even when the Recovery queue is sitting at 400G. That takes 8 hours to drain - leading to very unhappy Clients...

Comment: This is likely too broad to make a good question on [dba.se], unless you can really narrow this down to a particular problem area.  Put it this way, there is no "bottleneck" in *SQL Server* itself.

Comment: Take the [tour] and check the [help] for more details about what makes a good question.  We'd need a much greater level of detail about the server, such as is the storage on  a SAN, or is locally attached?  How much RAM is in the machine.  What is the page-life-expectancy.  How many databases reside on the replica.  Are both servers one the same LAN segment or are they thousands of miles apart?

Comment: You've touched on one of the items: It's single-threaded. SQL Server 2016 introduced multithreaded redo on Availability Groups. Additionally, I recall from a session at the (2015?) PASS Summit in which there was a suboptimal encryption/compression setting in the AG transfer codebase. Those may contribute to what you're seeing.The panelist who mentioned this noted that it was fixed in SQL Server 2014 (it was a "What's New In SQL Server 2014 Availability Groups" session).

Comment: What kind of speeds do you see when you copy a file across the same path?

Comment: Beyond that, look for transfer rates (per sp_BlitzErik), make sure your AV exceptions are correct, and that any network packet sniffers are eliminated from consideration (for instance, I had trouble with Carbon Black for a period of time).

Comment: Also make sure no one decided to QoS your AG network.

Answer (score 4):

> what is the bottleneck within SQL Server 2012 that stops it from maximizing the potential throughput and how can I overcome it?

That was a major work item in SQL 2016.

> The result is a design for SQL Server 2016 that provides high
>   availability for the most demanding workloads on the latest hardware
>   with minimal impact and scalable for the future. Our design for SQL
>   Server 2012 and SQL Server 2014 is still proven and meets the demands
>   for many of our customers. However, if you are looking to accelerate
>   your hardware, our Always On Availability Group design for SQL Server
>   2016 can keep pace.

See [SQL Server 2016 – It Just Runs Faster: Always On Availability Groups Turbocharged](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2016/09/26/sql-server-2016-it-just-runs-faster-always-on-availability-groups-turbocharged/)